# Get glyphicons thinner

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

Everyone! I'm trying to make glyphicons thinner, like this

[image]

Now I get this view of icon

[image]

Is there any solution to make it thinner? I tried to chnge font-size and font-weight, but it didn't help. What eles can I do?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want is going to be doable with just plain CSS - you may need to create a new glyph.

Comment: So, I can't customise this glyph, to make it look thinner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding the `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` property to your glyphicon? But that would not reduce the thickness that much, as in your example tho.